# R script using X11 window only opens for a second

Tags: r, x11

I'm running an R script via my Linux Mint 16 command line. It contains a boxplot that I want to display in a window. So I'm using x11() function for creating that window. Here is my code:

```
testdata <- data.frame(sample(1:1000,size=100,replace=T), row.names=NULL)
colnames(testdata)<-c("data")

x11()
boxplot(testdata, main="Boxplot der Testdaten", horizontal=TRUE)
```

When I run this function in Rstudio, it will open a window and show the boxplot created. But whenever I run it from the command line of my Linux Mint 16 machine, the window will open for a second and then close again. I can see the boxplot for a second. I couldn't really find a reason for this. I'm quite new to R and never used X11 before. Any ideas would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is that all there is to the script? Note that R exits when the script is finished which closes all open graphics devices.

Comment: Do you want to have your script save the plot? Or do you want to be able to use R at the commandline the same way you use RStudio?

Comment: I do not want to save it. I just need it to be shown on screen. You're right I wanted to use R in the commandline the same way as Rstudio. This is because it is for a project at uni and the task said we had to start the programme from the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more-or-less a FAQ.   Part of this is that you seem to misunderstand how all commands terminate. I.e. when you call `ls` it does not stop either.

So here you need to something extra.  Possibly approaches:

- Just sleep via  `Sys.sleep(10)`  which would wait ten seconds.
- Wait for user input via `readLines(stdin())` or something like that [untested]
- Use the tcltk package which comes with R and is available on all platforms to pop up a window the user has to click to make the click disappear.  That solution has been posted a few times over the years on r-help.

But in this day and age, you may also rethink the issue. I had good success preparing analysis and visualization for colleagues via the most-awesome [shiny](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=shiny) package which displays to a web page.  Everybody has a web browser...

Comment: I went for the solution using `readLines(stdin())`. This worked fine for me. I posted a "Press any key and Enter to close the window". After user input the window closes. It works both on my Linux Mint 16 machine starting the script with `Rscript X.R` as well as on my Windows 8.1 Command Line window using `Rscript.exe X.R` to start it. Now I'm looking into the tcltk package with is very nice and easy to use. In the end I think I'm gonna go tcltk. Work in progress. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. If you like the answer it is then customary to 'accept' (by clicking on the tickmark you as the question-asker see) and also 'upvote' (by clicking the 'up-triangle'). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not upvoting, my reputation is too low for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can sleep until all windows are closed

```
while(names(dev.cur()) !='null device') Sys.sleep(1)
```

on my machine, after calling `x11()`, `names(dev.cur())` is  "X11cairo". After closing all/any windows opened with x11, `names(dev.cur())` becomes "null device"

```
testdata <- data.frame(sample(1:1000,size=100,replace=T), row.names=NULL)
colnames(testdata)<-c("data")

x11()
boxplot(testdata, main="Boxplot der Testdaten", horizontal=TRUE)
# wait until window is closed (check every second)
while(names(dev.cur()) !='null device') Sys.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This was the way to go. However, after closing windows `dev.cur()` became "pdf" for me, so if you try this and it hangs, you might want to `print(names(dev.cur()))` in the while conditional to see what it changes to once you close the window and then handle it accordingly.